# Raw Bluetooth Advertisement via C / COM?

Tags: c, winapi

Good Afternoon,

Is there any way to dispatch a raw bluetooth advertisement via the standard C API or via some COM provider ? I've seen that there is a way via WINRT [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/10f3neg/winrtuwp_decode_bluetoothleadvertisement_in/?rdt=52766) however there is not a note of a way to do it say using raw sockets - Unless creating a raw socket / creating the raw header myself is a sufficient way, which, I'll do that instead if there isnt another option.

I mostly tried the raw socket way to no success - USing SOCK_RAW and it wasnt able to craft the raw buffer.

Comment: [`IOCTL_BTH_SDP_SUBMIT_RECORD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/bthioctl/ni-bthioctl-ioctl_bth_sdp_submit_record)

Comment: Note WinRT is based on COM, and you can use WinRT from C (it's a bit complex, ok), more and more Windows API are exposed only as WinRT interfaces.

Comment: some code used this ioctl [here](https://github.com/rbmm/BTH/blob/main/util.cpp#L40)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.